# Coin flipping game with three random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Ty, Guy and Pay are all flipping fair coins until they respectively obtain their first heads. $T, G$ and $P$ represent the number of flips needed for Ty, Guy and Pay, respectively. Find $\mathbb{P}(T\leq G\leq P)$.

My attempt was:

$\mathbb{P}(T\leq G \leq P) = \mathbb{P}(T\leq G \cap G\leq P) = \displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{P}(T\leq G | G\leq P)}{\mathbb{P}(G\leq P)}$

$\mathbb{P}(T\leq G | G\leq P) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(T\leq G | G\leq k \cap P=k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(T\leq G | G\leq k)\mathbb{P}(P=k)$

$\mathbb{P}(T\leq G | G \leq k) = \sum_{j=1}^{k}\mathbb{P}(T\leq G | G=j)$

$\mathbb{P}(T\leq G | G=j) = \mathbb{P}(T\leq j \cap G=j) = \sum_{i=1}^{j} \mathbb{P}(T=i)\mathbb{P}(G=j) = \frac{1}{2^j}\sum_{i=1}^{j}\frac{1}{2^i} = \frac{1}{2^j}-\frac{1}{4^j}$

Then going backwards gives me $\mathbb{P}(T\leq G | G\leq P) = \frac{8}{21}$

$\mathbb{P}(G\leq P) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(G\leq k \cap P=k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(G\leq k)\mathbb{P}(P=k)$

$\mathbb{P}(G\leq k) = \sum_{j=1}^{k}\mathbb{P}(G=j) = \sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2^j} = 1-\frac{1}{2^k}$

So $\mathbb{P}(G\leq P) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{2^k})\frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{2}{3}$

And so $\mathbb{P}(T\leq G \leq P) = \frac{8}{21}\div \frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{7}$,

But this is incorrect. Where have I gone wrong in my logic?

Comment: In the first line there is an error: you should have $P(T \le G \cap G \le P) = P(T \le G \mid G \le P) P(G \le P)$.

Comment: Oh yeah. Even so, $\frac{16}{63}$ is still not correct.

Comment: There are other errors, like $P(T \le G \mid G \le k \cap P = k) \ne P(T \le G \mid G \le k) P(P=k)$.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force:

\begin{align}
P(T \le G \le P)
&= \sum_{t \ge 1} \sum_{g \ge t} \sum_{p \ge g} P(T=t, G=g, P=p)
\\
&= \sum_{t \ge 1} \sum_{g \ge t} \sum_{p \ge g} P(T=t)P(G=g)P(P=p)
\\
&= \sum_{t \ge 1} 2^{-t} \sum_{g \ge t} 2^{-g} \sum_{p \ge g} 2^{-p}
\\
&= \sum_{t \ge 1} 2^{-t} \sum_{g \ge t} 2^{-g} 2^{-g} 2
\\
&= 2\sum_{t \ge 1} 2^{-t} \sum_{g \ge t} 4^{-g}
\\
&= 2 \sum_{t \ge 1} 2^{-t} 4^{-t} \frac{4}{3}
\\
&= \frac{8}{3} \sum_{t \ge 1} 8^{-t}
\\
&= \frac{8}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{8}{7}
\\
&= \frac{8}{21}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$\frac8{21}$ looks like the final answer for $P(T \le G \le P)$.  But I do not understand your calculations and you have this value for $P(T \le G \mid G \le P)$ which I think instead would be $\frac47$.

I would have started by looking at the probability $q =P(G \le P)$ by seeing what happens with the first pair of flips (HH, HT,TH, TT) and whether you need more flips

with $q=\frac14+\frac14+\frac04+\frac{q}4$ giving $\frac34q= \frac24$ and thus $q=\frac23$,

and then at $p=P(T \le G \le P)$ by looking at what happens with the first triple of flips (HHH,HHT,HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TTH, TTT) and whether you need more flips

with $p=\frac18 + \frac18 + \frac08 +\frac{q}{8}+ \frac08 + \frac08 + \frac08 + \frac{p}{8}$ giving $\frac78 p= \frac28 +  \frac q8$ and so $p=\frac8{21}$.